# The Bitcoin-Gold fork came before I expected.... can I still access my BTG?

Tags: blockchain-fork, bitcoin-gold

I transferred btc from gemini to a paper wallet around at 9:30pm Monday. Will I still be able to get my BTG? Where will they show up? I'm not sure when the "snapshot" was created.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://www.coindesk.com/bitcoin-gold-initiates-hard-fork-split-create-new-blockchain/), Bitcoin-Gold forked "at block 491,407 on the original blockchain".

If you look up your sending or receiving address in blockchain.info, and drill down into the transaction id, you should be able to find the block number that it was included in. This will allow you to work out whether your transaction was before or after the fork.

If you have access to the private key of an address where bitcoins were stored at the time of the fork, you should be able to get the BTG and the BTC as you have full control of them.

However, I believe Gemini is an exchange, so if you have bitcoins stored on the exchange at the time of the fork you'll be relying on them to give you any BTG you would otherwise have access to (assuming they don't give you access to the private key of the funds stored on the site... but exchanges usually don't).

Note that on 8th Oct 2017, Gemini [announced on Twitter](https://twitter.com/GeminiDotCom/status/916676395576758273) that they would [allow users to withdraw Bitcoin-Cash](https://gemini.com/blog/bitcoin-cash-bch-withdrawals/), which was created as a fork of Bitcoin in a similar way to Bitcoin-Gold. Perhaps this is a good indication they will do the same for Bitcoin-Gold.

Comment: Note that a new answer was added to this question stating _"Yes all of that is true. Many thanks. What I am asking is... Do we know if gemini exchange will be crediting wallets with btg Yes I had some btc on gemini at the time of the fork"_. This was probably not able to be posted as a comment due to the users reputation, so I've posted it here.

Comment: @Some-guy, I've edited my answer with some information that might help.